# How to Add smilies switcher for the given javascript for blogger

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

```
.emoWrap{position:relative;padding:10px;margin-bottom:7px;background:#efefef;background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right,#fff  0,#fff9f2 100%);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right,#fff  0,#fff9f2 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right,#fff 0,#fff9f2  100%);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left  top,color-stop(0,#fff),color-stop(1,#fff9f2));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right,#fff  0,#fff9f2 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to left,#fff 0,#fff9f2  100%);border:1px solid  #ccc;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:0  4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);-moz-box-shadow:0 4px  6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px  6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);box-shadow:0 2px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 1px 1px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-weight:normal;color:#333}.emoWrap:after{content:"";position:absolute;bottom:-10px;left:10px;border-top:10px  solid #ccc;border-right:20px solid  transparent;width:0;height:0;line-height:0}
```

Comment: Is there any javascript errors?

Comment: You should format your code properly. Not very readable...